# How to create a method and use it in another class?

Tags: java, android

I'm a new developer in Android and I have a question:

I want to create a class **xMetodos.java** that has all my methods and after that, use the method that I just created on class **TelaCadastroRestaurante.java.**

PS.: I know I have to create an object 
**xMetodos abc = new xMetodos();** and then call **abc.NameOfMethod**, or declare it as static, but this isn't working and I have no idea why.

Could please someone help me?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYDbi.png - WANT TO CALL RIGHT HERE

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CE11.png - GETTING THE METHOD FROM HERE

Comment: Set a `protected static myMethod(){...}` in class A. In class B, use it as `A.myMethod();`. Just as simple as this.

Comment: it doest worked... but FD_ solutions worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot instantiate an Activity yourself and just call one of its methods. Activities can only be correctly instantiated by the system, by opening them via an Intent. Although there is a constructor your can use, much of the Activity's underlying mechanisms (everything related to Contexts) require the Activity to be instantiated by the system. As you are calling `getApplicationContext()`, the Activity needs a `Context` to get the application context from. This `Context` is usually assigned by the system.

A solution would be to make the method static and let it take an argument of type `Context`:

```
public void a(Context context){...}
```

Then, call it from the other `Activity` like this:

```
a(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Dammmmmmnnn man, you're good.

Comment: Thanks a lot....

look what i just did

http://prntscr.com/6846yb AND http://prntscr.com/68472i
it worked perfectly